# Should toString be used for a complex operation?

Tags: java, string, tostring

I have a class named `CommandHelp`. It stores some strings that (obviously) describe what a command does, what are its aliases, the arguments it requires and whatever else I need to register about the command.

`CommandHelp.toString()` is a "complex" method as it does not return the command name or anything short such as "COMMAND: GOTO", instead it returns (usually) a 200+ character long `String` object.

The class also has a `toOneLineString()` method.

Question is:

Should `toString` - as a method's name - be avoided? Would it be considered a good practice (or a better practice) to use `toFullString` or `toFullCommandDescription` as that method's name?

EDIT: toString() was overriden. I was just asking if the method I implemented there should be refactored under another method name.

Answer (score 4):

The wisdom is that `toString()` should only be used for humans to read and developers should be free to change the implementation at will without impacting the program's behaviour.

Methods that produce a String that is relied on by other code to have a particular format should not involve `toString()` in any way.

Your idea of special methods seems on the right track. Consider using method names like `getDescription()`.